# Raspberry Pi emergency mode can't go into the system?

Tags: raspberry-pi

Raspberry Pi    emergency mode   can't go into the system?
It says as this :
Welcome to emergency mode! After logging in, type "journalctl -xb" to view
system logs, "systemctl reboot" to reboot, "systemctl default" to try again
to boot into default mode.
root@raspberrypi:~# _

Answer (score -1):

it came out this error ,because I have add "dev/sd0     /samba  " connect to the file "/dev/fstab", it can be solved by delete or comment the last sentence like this "# dev/sd0     /samba  "